# Will there be any issues connecting 2 loads to a single DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, split

I am working a project that involves 2 loads, a battery and an electronic DC load. The battery is connected to a charger which allows a power path from the battery to the DC load when the battery is discharging. The charger is also connected to a power supply which provides power to recharge the battery.

When the battery is recharging, power is not directed to the DC load from the charger. I wish to create an additional path from the power supply directly to the DC load so that during charging, the DC load will still receive power from the power supply.

Some parameters:

- DC power supply of maximum 30V and 100W
- DC load drawing constant power <100W
- Input voltage to the charger of 8.4V or higher
- LIPO 2S battery, 930mAh

Will there be any issues if I create the additional split by creating a Y split from the cable connected to the power supply?

[image: Schematic of setup]

Comment: The devil is in the detail and a block diagram is not "detail" plus it's ambiguous.

Comment: It is common practice to connect a charger, a battery and a load directly in parallel.  If the charger provides more current that the load requires, the excess charges the battery.  If the charger provides less current than the load requires, the battery supplies the difference - no switching required.